# PHP curl_init() could not initialize a new curl handle

Tags: php, curl

I have an class `proxy` with function `curl` and `test` which looks like this:

```
    class proxy {
    public static function test($thread){
         do{
            $t=fufunction($thread);
            $res=self::curl('http://foo.com/',$t);
            ...
        }while(1)
    }
    public static function curl($url,$proxy){
            $ecurl = curl_init($url);
            if(!$ecurl) {echo "\nFAILED CURL for $url\n"; sleep(60);exit;}
            if(!empty($xhead) && is_array($xhead)) curl_setopt($ecurl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $xhead);
            curl_setopt($ecurl, CURLOPT_MAXCONNECTS, 100);
            curl_setopt($ecurl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15);
            curl_setopt($ecurl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
            curl_setopt($ecurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ecurl, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($ecurl, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
            $ret= curl_exec($ecurl);
            curl_close($ecurl);
            unset($ecurl);
            return $ret;
        }
    }
```

When I use this script it fails after about 30000 curl request, with error `curl_init() could not initialize a new curl handle` 
I use this code to execute the script:

```
new proxy();
proxy::test('.$thread.');
```

Seems curl keep some resource locked? At first I thought that the problem was that I forgot to close curl connection, or to unset curl resource... I added `curl_close($ecurl)`
`unset($ecurl)` But it doesn't help.

Is there a way to free curl resource in running script, or at least to know the number of sockets available for use in curl?

Comment: Why are you creating an infinite loop which creates cURL requests non-stop to the same endpoint? It sounds to me like you're hitting some kind of system resource limit because you're creating requests so quickly.

Comment: The loop in not infinite. There was inner code with break condition, which were removed to simplify example script. The speed is not a problem. Probably for some reason there's no free socket left for curl to initiate... but I don't know how to check this.